# не передается Requestparam в axios get методе

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, spring-boot, axios

Всем привет. Не подскажете как я могу передать параметр в запрос на клиенте.Допустим я вбиваю адресной строке host:8081/api/greeting?name='Test' передается статика **Name** ,а хотелось бы чтобы он на сервер тоже передал **Test**. То есть он игнорируется мой requestparam

***Клиент***

```
 methods: {
    loadGreeting() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/greeting',
          {params: {name:'Name'}})
          .then(response => {
            this.$data.counter = response.data.id;
            this.$data.username = response.data.content;
          }).catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error.response.data);
      })
    }
  }
```

***Сервер***

```
 @GetMapping( "/greeting")
 fun greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name",defaultValue = "User") name : String)
```

Comment: обновил ответ ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ даётся при условии, что в данном примере:

- фронтенд запущен на хосте localhost:8081
- api запущен на  localhost:8080

## Доступ к параметрам запроса на фронтенде

Вам необходимо перехватить имя из параметров запроса с на фронтенде и передать его в помощью `axios` к `api`.

Во `Vue` это можно сделать с помощью компонента `Router`
У него есть свойство `query`. 
Это объект, который содержит в себе все парамерты запроса в виде `ключ:значение`

Соответственно для того чтобы получить парамерт `name`, вам необходимо обратиться к нему следующим образом:

```
this.$route.query.name
```

После чего метод `loadGreeting()` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```js
loadGreeting() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/greeting',
              {params: {name: this.$route.query.name} }
    ).then(response => {
        // ... тут ничего не изменилось
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error.response.data);
    })
}
```

Документация Router: https://router.vuejs.org/api/

## Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Как Вы сами заметили также стоит учитывать то, что когда фронтенд и api работают на разных хостах, могут блокироваться запросы в браузере между разными хостами.

Браузеры разрешают делать асинхронные запросы на тот же источник(`Same Origin`)
Остальные запросы будут блокироваться.

Источник является *"тем же"* если в нем указаны:

- тот же хост
- тот же порт
- тот же протокол

Соответственно, запрос между `localhost:8081` и `localhost:8080` будет заблокирован.

Для того, чтобы данный запрос не блокировался `localhost:8080` должен разрешить `localhost:8081` делать запросы к нему.
Для этого сервер должен в HTTP-ответе указать заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` в котором, должен быть указан хост(ы), которому мы доверяем, или шаблон, которому он удовлетворяет.

В Spring это можно реализовать проставив аннотацию `@CrossOrigin`

```kotlin
@GetMapping( "/greeting")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
fun greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name",defaultValue = "User") name : String)
```

CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: это никак не влияет.Можете посмотреть оф.документацию https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html (kotlin).

Comment: @Farkhutdinov, хорошо на котлине сейчас проверю и отпишусь

Comment: @Farkhutdinov, гайд я повторил и у меня все работает.
Можете привести полностью Ваш скрипт(я про vue) чтобы проще тестировать было?

Comment: @Farkhutdinov, если хотите, то можете мне в телеграм написать(он есть в профиле)

Comment: У вас есть контроллер и статика на одном хосте? Меня смущают у вас разные хосты. Плюс у вас отличается маршрут в axios запросе, от того что есть в гайде.

Answer (score 1):

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/greeting',
          {params: {name:this.$route.query.name}})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]